ExecuteNonQueryAsync 'A severe error occurred...'
I run a longtime running SQL query by clicking on GO button:
Await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(Me.cts.Token)
The command starts, lets say I have this query as part of corresponding command:
set nocount on;
declare @ID int=0
WHILE @ID<400000 BEGIN
    SET @ID+=1
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000'
END 

Now when I click Cancel button (which call cts.Cancel()) it causes SqlException, whichs containts 2 errors:

"A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded." (number 0)
"Operation cancelled by user." (number 0)

I also different queries including INSERT statements. Everything worked fine, data was properly written.
So what is wrong?

Please read this and edit your question accordingly.

It doesn't appear that anything is wrong.  You should expect that when you signal a cancel on the cancellation token, a System.OperationCanceledException will be raised.  In this case, it looks like the SQL client is wrapping that inner exception into a SqlException, but you can still find it by looking into the inner exception.

So you want to say that text 'severe error' doesn't really mean there was a serious error running the sal statement?

I would tend to agree that cancellation is not "a severe error", but other than the message text (which I treat as informative for the developer but not useful to the user anyway) I don't see any problems.

I was threatened by the word severe. So basically the message is for programmer which should take this into account by let's say adding code for sql Transaction - let's say adding transaction.Rollback() when this SqlException appears, right?

I think that's reasonable.  In my own cancel-handling code, I include OperationCanceledException as part of the routine exception handling (with certain workflows expected to issue it).
